# providing login check, page redirect for all pages in php

Tags: php, database, oracle, authentication, logout

Here is my code if refresh my page its logout or also while when I change menu bar its also logout why?

```
    <?php
$userid = ($_POST['userid']);
$pswd = ($_POST['pswd']);
$conn = oci_connect('user', 'pswrd', 'db');
$query = "SELECT userid, pswd FROM staff
WHERE userid=:userid AND pswd=:pswd";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':userid', $userid, 8);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':pswd', $pswd, 32);
oci_execute($stmt);
list($userid, $pswd) = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_NUM);
if ($userid != "" && $pswd !="")
{
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
echo " logged in sucessfully!!!...";
}
else {
    echo"you are not logged in ";
    }
?>
```

Comment: where do you call `session_start`?

Comment: Strange is you login with 'userid'. Usually we login with 'username' and 'password'

Comment: In your folder\login.php page check session is set or not then redirect to your desired page on top. Like 

`session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        header("Location: example.php");
    }`

Comment: Post your html code too

Answer (score 0):

You could use `javascript` or php `header` to redirect to specific page in your application.

```
<?php
if ($userid != "" && $pswd !="")
{
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
?>
<script> window.location ="http://www.yourwebsite.com/user.php";</script>
<?php 
}?>
```

**Or** use php `header`

```
if ($userid != "" && $pswd !="")
{
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/user.php");
}
```

Comment: @NA05 you are getting error at `line4`. So, that's not because of my solution. That's might be because of, `$_POST['pswd']`, check whether this value is populated `isset($_POST['pswd'])` will return true if it have some value

Comment: @NA05 If you are getting logout, that only means, you are not maintaining session. Do you have `session_start()` at very top ? Make sure, you are properly managing the session.

Comment: @NA05 not sure, what are you expecting and what is your question now. I would say, you are doing something wrong. not sure what. Now, I will make it simple, if you try accessing index of any array for example `$_post`, which is not populated, then you will get error `Undefined index`.

Comment: @NA05 if you are getting logged out, means your session is not active. That is obvious

Answer (score 0):

To use Sessions, you first need to tell PHP to look for them. For that, first call "session_start();".

You then should check if a Session is set. Do this with isset($_SESSION['varname']). You can optionally set a Session for checking the login_state. Here you could save a timestamp and check, if the user has been "inactive" for a while. Ofcourse, this is only a simple way.

Further: When expecting request, always first check if they are set.

eg. isset($_POST['varname'])

```
<?php
session_start();

$display_page = false;

if(
    isset($_SESSION['userid'])
 && isset($_SESSION['logged'])
 && (time()-$_SESSION['logged'] < 60 * 30) // 30 Minutes
) {
    $display_page = true;
}

if(!$display_page) {
    if(!isset($_POST['userid'])) die("No userid given");
    $userid = ($_POST['userid']);
    if(!isset($_POST['pswd'])) die("No password given");
    $pswd = ($_POST['pswd']);
    $conn = oci_connect('user', 'pswrd', 'db');
    $query = "SELECT userid, pswd FROM staff
    WHERE userid=:userid AND pswd=:pswd";
    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':userid', $userid, 8);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':pswd', $pswd, 32);
    oci_execute($stmt);
    list($userid, $pswd) = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_NUM);
    if ($userid != "" && $pswd !="")
    {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
        $_SESSION['logged'] = time();
        echo "You just logged in sucessfully!!!...<br>";
        $display_page = true;
    } else {
        echo "Your credentials did not match. Pleas try again";
    }
}

if($display_page) {
    echo "This is the page content";
}
?>
```

If you want something like "if not logged in, redirect to login page", you should use the following:

```
if(!$display_page) {
    header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/login.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the code exactly as I wrote it? What PHP version are you using? Have you denied cookies in your browser?

Comment: On my computer this works. I suggest you check your environment. What is your PHP version? Did you turn of cookies in your browser? For PHP7.1 there once was a bug, that sessions had to be saved as cookies or something.